# Scss files not compiling using Gulp

Tags: html, sass, gulp

I'm getting this issue whereby I'm trying to compile my scss files, but I'm getting this error:

```
$ gulp
[17:02:35] Using gulpfile C:\wamp\www\testsite\gulpfile.js
[17:02:35] Starting 'sass'...
[17:02:35] Starting 'copy-imgs'...
[17:02:35] Finished 'copy-imgs' after 4.14 ms
[17:02:35] Starting 'copy-assets'...
[17:02:35] Finished 'copy-assets' after 8.03 μs
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    testsite\sass\test\_blog.scss
Error: Undefined variable: "$lt-small".
        on line 19 of testsite/sass/test/_blog.scss
>>         @media($lt_small) {
```

The issue is that I have a variables.scss file, defining these variables, at the same (folder) level. So a little unsure as to why they are coming back undefined? Does the variables.scss need to sit somewhere else within the structure?

Apologies if this is vague.

Answer (score 1):

It already says the error;

```
Undefined variable: "$lt-small".
```

The `$lt-small` has to be defined before used

Also you have to import your `variables.scss` file before `_blog.scss` file.

Answer (score 0):

Always be sure that your importing order is correct. If you try to use a variable before you declare them, sass will throw error.

Moreover variables.scss should be a partial file i guess. However your blog.scss that i assume will be your main scss file should not be a partial file.

Partial files are marked with an _ before the filename. Partial files are get no compiled to css but their content will be compiled on import.